# Read a binary file in MatLab

Tags: c++, matlab

In C++, I wrote my data in a binary file. My data is like this: `float data[a][b]` (this is in C++). Now, i just want to read this binary file from Matlab (of course, I am pretty new in matlab), to get the A array ( `A = data[a][b]` ). I search many solutions in google such as:

```
frid = fopen('data.bin', 'rb');
A = fread(fid,count,type)
...
```

However, maybe because I'm new, those solutions don't work for me!

Can anyone give me a suggestion to read this data? Any answer is welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Look at the documentation for the fread function (google "matlab fread"). fread requires the file pointer ("frid"), the number of items to read, and the type. You'll have to see what binary type your data are. So it would look something like:

```
A = fread(frid, 100, 'real*4');
```

Where 100 is the number of elements to read.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have the right answer. For your case, you need

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','rb');
A = fread(fid,[rows cols],'float');
```

I'm assuming that although you wrote 'data.txt' for the file name, the file is not actually a text file. You may need to transpose `A` to get the layout you expect depending on how you wrote the data originally.

Answer (score 0):

what is the extension of your data? if it is in *.txt file then you can open it by

data = textread('myfile.txt','%f');

go to http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textread.html for more help...

Comment: This question seems pretty clear that the data are "in a binary file".  The file extension has nothing to do with whether `textread` can be used, only the format determines that.  And `textread` doesn't help with binary formats.